# Mysterious page route - where is it coming from?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have this custom convention:

```
public class RegionLanguagePageRouteModelConvention : IPageRouteModelConvention
    {
        public void Apply(PageRouteModel model)
        {
            foreach (var selector in model.Selectors.ToList())
            {
                if (selector.AttributeRouteModel.Template == "Index")
                {
                    model.Selectors.Remove(selector);
                }

                if (selector.AttributeRouteModel.Template == "")
                {
                    model.Selectors.Add(new SelectorModel
                    {
                        AttributeRouteModel = new AttributeRouteModel
                        {
                            Template = AttributeRouteModel.CombineTemplates("{regionParam1}/{languageParam2}-{regionParam3}/{slugParam4}", selector.AttributeRouteModel.Template)
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Now when I inspect `RouteData.Values` in `OnGet()` on my `IndexModel` there's a completely new Key/Value pair in the `RouteData.Values` collection that I've never seen before:

```
Key: "page"
Value: "/Index"
```

How did it get there? I was expecting:

```
Key: ""
Value: ""
```

..because I removed the "Index" template in my custom convention class and left only the "" one.

Also, when setting a break point in `RegionLanguagePageRouteModelConvention` while iterating the `foreach` loop I can't see the "page" (key) / "Index" (value) template in any of the pages / selectors.